# Handlebars {{#if}} does not render as expected

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js

I observe some very strage behavior. When using `{{#if}}` inside a `div` class tag:

```
<div class="gallery-row {{#if helper}}class2{{/if}}">
```

I get the following DOM fragment:

```
<div class="gallery-row <!--data:Hb4bubiKDcedk9Z85-->">
```

I have similar `{{#if}}` clauses in other class definitions. When I use the `{{#if}}` outside the div tag it seems to work fine. I guess I did some silly mistake or there is a bug here.

Comment: What does the "helper"-helper return?

Comment: true or false. But should it matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment is a spark (meteor's templating system) annotation, which don't work well inside HTML tags (as html comments are invalid inside them). This is known issue, see: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/800.

Move your helpers outside the tags.

```
{{#if helper}}
    <div class="class1 class2">
{{else}}
    <div class="class1">
{{/if}}
```

Or create a helper for `classes` and use `<div class="{{classes}}">` instead

Comment: That's strage. I use this notation in other places throughout my source and it works fine. Regarding your suggestion with `{{#if}}`, are you sure I can write a partial element (without closing) inside a block (`{{#if}}`)? I already created a helper but I would prefer to leav class names out of my js code.

Comment: Afaik the block helpers sometimes cause problems (ones with '#' in them). But the other ones don't use spark annotations in the compiled handlebars source so they shouldn't be an issue.